# TSql: Left Join no matching fields

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a date table and a numbers table. I want to join them to create Date Hour table where I will have a date with each hour of the day.

**Date Table**

```
mydate
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04 ...
```

**Numbers table**

```
digit
  0
  1
  2
  3 ...
```

**Desired Result**

```
mydate        hour
2013-01-01     0
2013-01-01     1
2013-01-01     2
2013-01-01     3 ...
2013-01-02     0
2013-01-02     1
2013-01-02     2
2013-01-02     3 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are the only columns you should just be able to join with no conditions, as that will give you every possible combination since it is not restricted. Then just order it with an order by statement and :

```
SELECT   a.mydate,
         b.digit
FROM     date_table  a
JOIN     digit_table b
ORDER BY a.mydate, b.digit
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a CROSS JOIN for this purpose. The syntax is like this

```
SELECT CAST(dateTable.myDate as nvarchar)+' '+ numbersTable.digit
FROM dateTable
CROSS JOIN numbersTable
```

Comment: correct suggestion but beware of cross joins if your tables are large as it is a Cartesian product!